# How to edit own profile in activeadmin and devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I tried to search the answer in many resources but could not find it. Also could not see it in routes.

I have:

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

Comment: Do you see `Admin Users` tab in your active admin panel?

Comment: You mean AdminUser resource? Yes, but it allows to manage all users. But I need a separate page to edit only own profile.

Comment: In vanilla Devise `devise_for :admin_users` would create the helper `edit_admin_users_path` and the path `/admin_users/edit` which is handled by `Devise::RegistrationsController#edit` - the route has no id segment since it only edits the signed in user. I have no idea what `ActiveAdmin::Devise.config` contains but you could just use byebug or pry to insert a  breakpoint and inspect it and see if it changes the routes or skips them.